# how to do a bulk transaction with different tokens in a smart contract?

Tags: transactions, token, solidity, smartcontracts

I have this smart contract I found on github that is able to send multiple transactions but they all should be for the same token. but what I want is a smart contract that sends multiple transactions for different tokens like the picture I added, if anyone knows how let me know or send a link to a similar smart contract or project.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the `transfer()` (sending tokens from your contract) or `transferFrom()` (sending tokens from other address, need to have prior approval) functions on multiple token contracts.

Assuming that `from` address has approved `MyContract` address to operate their tokens (both `token1` and `token2`), the example below transfers both `token1` and `token2` within one transaction.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract MyContract {
    function batchTransfer(address token1, address token2, address from, address to, uint256 amount) public {
        bool success1 = IERC20(token1).transferFrom(from, to, amount);
        bool success2 = IERC20(token2).transferFrom(from, to, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: can we make it an array and put it in a loop something like?

Comment: `bool success[i] = IERC20(token[i]).transferFrom(from, to[i], amount[i]);`